# Show $A\cup B$ is denumerable by constructing a bijection

Tags: proof-explanation

I just need  some clarifications in the solution to the problem my teacher gave me below:

Suppose A and B are disjoint denumerable sets. Show that $A\cup B$ is denumerable by constructing a bijection.

proof: Since A and B are denumerable, then f:N->A and g:N->B are bijective.

h:N->$A\cup B$ is defined by :

h(n)= { $f(\frac{n+1}2)$ if n is odd and $g(\frac{n}2)$ if n is even)

From what I know, to now show bijection, I would have to prove surjectivity and injectivity. But my question here is why h(n) was defined like this. Why is my teacher saying h(n)= { $f(\frac{n+1}2)$ if n is odd and $g(\frac{n}2)$ if n is even). I was just wondering if the g and f could be switched. Like h(n)= { $g(\frac{n+1}2)$ if n is odd and $f(\frac{n}2)$ if n is even).

Comment: Have you seen a zipper? They are taking one element from the sequence $f$, then one from $g$, then one from $f$ and one from $g$, ...

Comment: I kind of get what you mean. Is it because since we taking from f first, and g second that my teacher structured it this way?

Comment: You're right that it wouldn't matter if $f$ and $g$ were switched! The point is that we just need to alternate between picking elements from $A$ and $B$ in a zig-zaggy (or zippery) way, so that we are guaranteed to eventually hit all elements in both exactly once. It doesn't matter if we start with an element from $A$ or an element from $B$.